# How to print out the ! in pyaml?

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I have code to print out a dict as YAML as so:

```
    import yaml
    yaml.dump(
        {
        "Properties":
             {
                 "ImageId": "!Ref AParameter"
             }
        },
        new_template,
        default_flow_style=False
    )
```

This creates:

```
Properties:
  ImageId: '!Ref AParameter'
```

Notice how the value for ImageId is inside quotes? I would like to print without the quotes. How do I do that with PyYAML?

Comment: `!` has a special meaning in YAML. Printing the value without quotes would change the meaning of the YAML.

Comment: Maybe. However, I do want it to be that way.

Comment: @doles It would be helpful if you explained what makes you "like" the output without quotes. It is not entirely clear that you understand the implications for programs loading the output you generate. I provided a solution for your exact output, with the necessary code for loading the output.

Comment: Sure. I am trying to programmatically create an AWS cloudformation template (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-reference.html) . In AWS cloudformation templates, a value can be a reference to another value somewhere else in the template. Such a reference is coded by using the syntax in my question. Hence, I want to be able to print out what I have asked. I can try alternate forms, but, that is the prescribed format.

Comment: @doles I did not find an example to `!Ref` there (but then I did not browse all the pages). If AWS assumes you write the YAML file by hand then including `!Ref` is of course trivial, but dumping that from a data structure is more convoluted as per my answer. Although with a conforming YAML parser `!Ref "AParameter"` should always load the same as `!Ref AParameter`.

Comment: Here is a link showing references: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html What you say is right. It should be able to take `!Ref "AParameter"` just as `!Ref AParameter`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` has a special meaning, as it is used to introduce [an explicit tag](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761292), and therefore cannot appear at the beginning of a plain (unquoted) style scalar. Specifically [rule 126](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#ns-plain-first(c)) of the YAML 1.2 specification indicates that the first character of such a plain scalar cannot be a [`c-indicator`](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#c-indicator), which is what `!` is.

Such a scalar has to be quoted (single or double) which PyYAML does automatically, or be put in a literal or folding block style.

You could dump valid YAML without quotes to a literal block style scalar:

```
Properties:
  ImageId: |
    !Ref AParameter
```

Without supportive programming PyYAML cannot do this. You can use ruamel.yaml to do so (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) by making the value a `PreservedScalarString` instance: `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.PreservedScalarString("!Ref AParameter")`

You can of course define a class that dumps using the `!Ref` tag, but the tag context will force quotes around the scalar `AParameter`:

```
import sys
import yaml

class Ref(str):
    @staticmethod
    def yaml_dumper(dumper, data):
        return dumper.represent_scalar('!Ref', u'{}'.format(data), style=None)

yaml.add_representer(Ref, Ref.yaml_dumper)


yaml.dump(
    {
        "Properties":
        {
            "ImageId": Ref("AParameter"),
        }
    },
    sys.stdout,
    default_flow_style=False,
)
```

which gives:

```
Properties:
  ImageId: !Ref 'AParameter'
```

This although loading `!Ref Aparameter` with an appropriate constructor **is** possible (i.e. the quotes are just added here to be on the safe side).

If you also want to suppress those quotes, you can e.g. do so using ruamel.yaml, by defining a special style `'x'` for your node and providing emitting processing for that:

```
from ruamel import yaml

class Ref(str):
    @staticmethod
    def yaml_dumper(dumper, data):
        return dumper.represent_scalar('!Ref', u'{}'.format(data), style='x')

    @staticmethod
    def yaml_constructor(loader, node):
        value = loader.construct_scalar(node)
        return Ref(value)

yaml.add_representer(Ref, Ref.yaml_dumper)
yaml.add_constructor('!Ref', Ref.yaml_constructor,
                     constructor=yaml.constructor.SafeConstructor)

def choose_scalar_style(self):
    if self.event.style == 'x':
        return ''
    return self.org_choose_scalar_style()

yaml.emitter.Emitter.org_choose_scalar_style = yaml.emitter.Emitter.choose_scalar_style
yaml.emitter.Emitter.choose_scalar_style = choose_scalar_style

data =  {
    "Properties":
    {
        "ImageId": Ref("AParameter"),
    }
}

ys = yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False)

print(ys)
data_out = yaml.safe_load(ys)
assert data_out == data
```

the above doesn't throw an error on the assert, so the data round-trips and the printed output is AFAICT exactly what you want:

```
Properties:
  ImageId: !Ref AParameter
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks for the detailed response. I will try this out very soon.

Comment: I tried it out and it indeed prints out what I wanted. The penultimate line fails because of `TypeError: unbound method yaml_constructor() must be called with Ref instance as first argument (got SafeLoader instance instead)`. Hence, the assert is never evaluated. But, it works.

Comment: @doles `yaml_constructor()` has to be decorated `@static_method`, just like `yaml_dumper()`, I updated the answer. Sorry for that.